# If adding the average to a collection of numbers, will the average of the collection change?

Tags: arithmetic, average

Consider the collection of integer numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ having the average `avg` - also an integer number.

Will adding `avg` itself to the collection change the average of the collection i.e. will the average of $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, \text{avg}\}$ also be `avg` ?

Simple examples seem to show this holds:

Ex1:
$\{2, 2, 4, 4\}$, with avg = $3$. We have $\{2, 2, 4, 4, 3\}$ with average also being $3$.

Is this always true?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  See if you can prove it algebraically.

Comment: "avg" has the property that the sum of $a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_n$ is nothing else than $n\cdot avg$. If we add "avg" to the collection the sum is now $(n+1)\cdot avg$. If we divide this by the number of elements ($n+1$) , we get again "avg".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. The average of a tuple $a = (a_1,...,a_n)$ is \begin{align*}\overline a = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\end{align*}
So if $\overline a$ is the average of $a = (a_1,...a_n)$ and $b = (a_1,...,a_n,\overline a)$, then the average of $b$ is
\begin{align*}\overline b &= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_i = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i + \overline a}{n+1}\\ &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n+1} \\ &=  \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{n\sum_{i=1}^na_i + \sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}\\&= \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n} =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}  = \overline a\end{align*}

Comment: Amazing, thanks !