# How to solve the average?

Tags: arithmetic, average

Question:
"The average marks of the students in four sections A,B,C and D together is 60 %. The average marks of the students of A,B,C and D individually are 45%,50%,72% and 80% respectively. If the average marks of the students of sections A and B together is 48% and that of the students of B and C together is 60%.What is the ratio of number of students in sections A and D?"

This particular type of questions conjecture the usage of an applied formulation of known average to estimate the other value. Like four sticks average 600 mm would mean 5th stick to be of length 600 mm only. I am not asking for the theoritical explanation but the details of what the rule actually means.

For example,If the average of two quantity is a particular value then the average of the other two value will be same as the combined average. I think this is a very frequently encountered property but please explain me why this works?

Comment: The question is unclear: of which rule do you ask the meaning but not the theoretical explanation?

Comment: Every one who has visited a school can safely assume that the average is the arithmetic one and is known to be \begin{align}
60\%=\frac{\sum_{s\in A}m_s+\sum_{s\in B}m_s+\sum_{s\in C}m_s+\sum_{s\in D}m_s}{|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|}
\end{align} where $m_s$ is the mark of student $s$. Set up six other such equations with the information you have and try to solve for the ratio of $|A|$ and $|D|$.

Comment: @Gribouillis I am asking where does this rule basically work ? That if the average of two quantity is a particular value then the average of the other two value will be same as the combined average. I think this is a very frequently encountered property but please explain me why this works?

Comment: Is anyone here able to as a question clearly ? @RajorshiKoyal : do you mean when does the following hold ? \begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sum_{s\in A}m_s+\sum_{s\in B}m_s}{|A|+|B|}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sum_{s\in C}m_s+\sum_{s\in D}m_s}{|C|+|D|}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{s\in A}m_s+\sum_{s\in B}m_s+\sum_{s\in C}m_s+\sum_{s\in D}m_s}{|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|}
\end{align}

Comment: Is this what you are want to know: [If adding the average to a collection of numbers, will the average of the collection change?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268610/139123) This also seems related: [Is the average of the averages equal to the average of all the numbers originally averaged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268610/139123) (The answer to the second question is "no" in general, but there are cases, including what I think you have in mind, where the answer is "yes".)